# nodejs express faster way to publish/push/send all files to client

Tags: node.js, express

i find nodejs express as the best and fastest way to build a quick web app for say prototyping as you only need a few lines and HTML/JS files and you can have a running webapp in no time.
The only problem I am seing is if say for example if I need to test something and it depends or uses more than 1 resource files such as JS, images, css, what I do for now is I manualy add them to app.get, individualy, like so

```
app.get('/js/dependency1.js', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, './js/dependency1.js'));
});
...
app.get('/js/dependency10.js', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, './js/dependency10.js'));
});

//... and so on for all images, etc.
```

This is tedious if I want to say, just test a library i downloaded,
Is there a way to push or send multiple files altogether in say a folder in nodejs express?

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to serve static assets like JS/Images/CSS is using [express.static(...)](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

From the official docs -

```js
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

Here, a directory named `public` will contain all your required client-side assets like JS/Images/CSS. The docs contain more verbose examples that show different ways of serving static assets using Express.